# What's the difference between ready and synchronized in pg_subscription_rel?

Tags: postgresql

What are the semantic differences between a value of `r` and `s` for the column `srsubstate` in `pg_subscription_rel`? The docs say that `r` means `ready` and `s` means `synchronized` but it's not clear to me what the difference between the two is.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-subscription-rel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a period after the table has been copied, when changes are being replayed to that table one at a time, but not yet coordinated so all changes to different tables in the set are replayed together in a single transaction (because some other table are still being copied).  The 's' state has something to do with this transition from uncoordinated to coordinated replay.  It doesn't seem to me like a particularly useful thing to expose to the user, but maybe it has a utility I just don't understand.